# Save Global variables BASH

Tags: bash, variables, export, global-variables

I am new at bash and trying to solve some issues for a code I'm trying to make.

I am at the terminal under my user name and connect to bash

```
USER$  
USER$ bash  
bash$
```

now in the bash I am saving some variables f.e:

```
i=2   
k=2   
let p=$k*$i
```

now I want to use those variables outside the bash function

```
bash$exit   
USER$
```

but now the variables are not there

I try using export, but it did not really work, could use ur help, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a DOS batch file, a Unix shell script cannot directly affect the environment of its calling shell.

You could consider using the `.` (dot) or `source` command to read and execute the script in the context of the calling shell.  This means that changes made in the script do affect the environment (in general; you can still run into issues with sub-shells).

The other alternative is to have the script that sets the variables write the values in `name=value` format into a file which the calling script then reads (with `.` or `source` again).

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. You cannot set environment variables in a parent process like this.

Comment: Ok, during my operation I need to move through 4 different servers, and each time I need the variables with me, what do u reccomend?

Answer (score 1):

The conventional solution is to add the settings to your `.profile` or `. bashrc` -- which you should use depends on your specific needs and your local Bash configuration; my first recommendation would be `.profile`, but then you have to avoid any bashisms because this file is shared with `sh` (so, no `let`, for example).

For more specific needs, put the commands in a file, and `source` it when you need it. You might also want to create a simple script to update the file with your current values.

```
# source this file to update $HOME/stuff

cat<<HERE>$HOME/stuff
i='$i'
k='$k'
p='$p'
export i k p
HERE
```

The syntax here is quite simple, but assumes you don't have values which can contain single quotes or otherwise free-form content. How to safely store arbitrary values which you don't have complete control over is a much more complex discussion; I am providing a simple solution for the basic use case where you merely need to save a few simple scalar values, like numbers.

To keep your variables when you connect to a remote system, look at the documentation for the tool you are using to connect. For example, `ssh` has configuration options for importing environment variables from the local system when starting a remote session.

Comment: Serious security issues here. `declare -p i k p >~/stuff` would be much safer if you were okay with making things bash-only. If one weren't, I would be tempted to use the Python `shlex.quote()` function to generate sh-compatible assignments with correct/safe escaping.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the comment; updated with a paragraph to somewhat hedge users from blindly adopting this for unsafe values.